# Setting Flask app instance to configuration

Tags: flask

I'm using blueprints with an application factory, so I cannot import the app instance. Do you guys see anything wrong with setting `app` to your config?

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['app'] = app
    with app.app_context():
        configure_app(app)
        configure_blueprints(app)
        ...
```

Now `app` can be accessed from a different module via `current_app.config['app']`

```
app = current_app.config['app']
with app.app_context():
    ...
```

Here it is in a real example:

```
from flask import current_app

def send_async_email(current_app, msg):
    with current_app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    Thread(target=send_async_email,
           args=(current_app.config['app'], msg)).start()
```

Using `current_app` alone in the `Thread` arguments, I get an error saying I'm working outside of the application context. Using current_app.config['app'] does work, I just want to know if there is a different way, or if there is anything wrong with doing it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `current_app` is just a proxy to the thread local app. This should solve it:

`app= current_app._get_current_object()`

This hands you back the original app object. Your config example worked because it also uses the original app not  the proxy.

Now you can pass it on the your new thread as such:

`Thread(target=send_async_email, args=(app, msg)).start()`

That being said, it's a bad idea setting your app as an item of your app.config as it's recursive.